# VBA move data from multiple activex controls to sheet2 when button is activated

Tags: vba

We have moved away from this solution, thanks for investing time into this, but we are using a normal userform instead :D

We want to move the data from the multiple ActiveX modules in Sheet 1.
And insert into Sheet 2 in the next empty cell.

Picture shows what we have in Sheet 1 and the ActiveX Modules.

[image]

We have tried to start the macro for the button with this (changed) anyone that can tell us what there might be missing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub CommandButton1_Click()


If ComboBoxName And ComboBoxTMS And TextBoxDate And TextBoxHour And ComboBoxOtherT And ComboBoxPlacment = "" Then
If True Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = ComboBoxName.Text
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value = TextBoxDate.Text
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 3).Value = TextBoxHour.Text
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 4).Value = ComboBoxTMS.Text
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 5).Value = ComboBoxOtherT.Text
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 7).Value = ComboBoxPlacement.Text
Else
msgBox = "Mssing value in one of these: " & "Name, Date, Hour, TMS, other timeregistration or Placement"

If TextBoxComment = "" Then
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 6).Value
End If
End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: What is it that you need to know/what's going wrong?

Comment: How to come further, i cant figure out how to write the VBA for the activex when they are NOT in a userform, but directly in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like so:

```
Dim w As Excel.Worksheet
Dim s As Shape
Dim o As OLEObject
Dim t As Object

Set w = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set s = w.Shapes("Textbox1")
Set o = s.OLEFormat.Object
Set t = o.Object

Debug.Print t.Text
```

Comment: But isnt that only for one avtivex control? i get a little confused with the letters.. :(  and are it supposed to be linked together with that i have already written ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit too broad. But to give you a start, you can use something like this to go through all `ActiveX` controls in your sheet

```
Sub GetAllShapes()

    Dim oWS As Worksheet: Set oWS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim oShp As Shape

    For Each oShp In oWS.Shapes
        MsgBox oShp.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You may just add the name of your sheet1, like e.g.:

```
Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheet1.ComboBoxName.Text
' and so on
```